# Maximum value of $\int (aF^2(x)g(x)+G^2(x)f(x))dx$ over all $f,g$ densities satisfying $\int F(x)g(x)dx=1/2$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, inequalities, nonlinear-optimization

> I want to maximise $$I(f,g):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (aF^2(x)g(x)+G^2(x)f(x))dx$$ where $a>0$ is a given constant, over all possible probability densities $f,g$ satisfying $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)g(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(x)f(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$$ where $G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)dt$ and $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$.

Recall $f,g$ are densities means $f\geq0,g\geq0,\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx=1$. Note that $F$ is cdf of $f$ and $G$ is cdf of $g$ so in other words $G'(x)=g(x)$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Since $F,G$ are cdf's, if we just have $\int F(x)g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ then it implies $\int G(x)f(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$ by change of variables formula so just one constraint is enough. Also, if it helps, $\int G(x)g(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}, \int G^2(x)g(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{3}$, and same for $f,F$.

> I worked out some cases and have a strong feeling that the maximum value is $\max(\dfrac{a}{4}+\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4})$. In particular, the maximum is $\dfrac{a}{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}$ if $a<1$ else the maximum is $\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$.

This is achieved when for example, $f$ (or $g$) is supported entirely between two humps of $g$ (or $f$) i.e. for example a situation where $f$ (or $g$) is supported on $[a_1,a_2]$, and $g$ (or $f$) is supported equally on $[b_1,b_2]$ and $[c_1,c_2]$ where $b_2<a_1<a_2<c_1$.

Many of my cases seem to tell me that this is the "extremal" situation. In fact, observe that $\int F^2(x)g(x)dx\leq \int F(x)g(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$ according to the constraint, and equality is achieved precisely when one density lies between two humps of the other, and in this case the value of the other integral is forced to be $\dfrac{1}{4}$. So the value of $I(f,g)$ is $\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$. Analogously $\int G^2(x)f(x)dx \leq \int G(x)f(x)dx =\dfrac{1}{2}$ and equality is achieved iff the other integral equals $\dfrac{1}{4}$ leading to the value of $I(f,g)=\dfrac{a}{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}$. So it seems to me that my guess for the maximum value of $I(f,g)$ is perhaps correct, but I am not able to prove it exactly.

I am also interested in knowing how one would approach such problems in general.